# Any way to automatically forward gmail after labeling it?

Tags: email, gmail, gtd

I currently use a Chrome add-on called Active-Inbox to manage my Gmail with labels in a GTD framework.  I am looking at other GTD solutions like Nozbe and Zendone.  Nozbe at least (maybe Zendone as well) and others allow you to forward emails to your account and have them become tasks.  What I'd love to be able to do is to mark a given email as "Next Action" in Gmail via ActiveInbox, which essentially just labels it, and have that trigger an email forward of that particular email to my Nozbe address.  IFTTT only has triggers for new mail with a given label, and gmail filtering doesn't seem to have an option for doing something based on a label being assigned.  Could be there is no way to get this done currently, but maybe there's a workaround or service that I'm just not thinking of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Google Docs to forward mail based on Gmail labels. [Here's a short how-to](http://lifehacker.com/5873647/auto+forward-past-and-future-emails-in-gmail).

Comment: Wow, fantastic!  Thanks so much, going to try this out now.

Comment: I set this up and it worked with Nozbe pretty well.  Really the only issue is that if you have a thread that you label, it will send each message in the thread individually rather than just one for the entire thread.

It would also be nice to be able to control some other aspects, but this does the trick for the most part, you just have to do a lot of pruning due to the additional entries for each separate message...

Comment: Glad it worked out. Thanks for highlighting the issue with threads too. I hadn't thought of that before.

Comment: The other issue I had was that at least for a while, the items I had deleted would come back.  I'm new to Nozbe so don't know if this is there own issue, but I'm assuming not, that somehow the script was reforwarding the emails even though I'd subsequently removed the tags that were supposed to trigger them.  That issue seems to have gone away, and now that I've paired down what was a list of over a hundred threads to only a handful, that if the issue does recur, it will be a lot easier to determine where the cause lies...

Comment: It already upgraded to workspace addon - but comments are not so good, and it wants too many dependencies for the addon. Read mail setra...